# Apparent contradiction in linear operator theory

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, banach-spaces

I'm confused by what appears to be a contradiction in linear operator theory. I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something and I'd like to understand why this doesn't work.

Suppose $A$ is a bounded injective compact linear operator with dense range on some Banach space $B$. Now my understanding is that if $B$ is infinite-dimensional then the range of $A$ must be a proper subset of $B$ and the inverse $A^{-1}$ is not bounded. However, the inverse is closed. Now consider the operator given by the composition $A\circ A^{-1}$ which also must be closed. Now, because $A$ has dense range in $B$ the domain of $A^{-1}$ must be dense. Hence for any $f\in B$ there is a sequence ${f_n}$ in the domain of $A^{-1}$ so that $f_n \to f$ and then we also have that $(A\circ A^{-1})f_n \to f$ but by closedness of $A\circ A^{-1}$ this means $f$ is in the domain of $A\circ A^{-1}$. But $f$ was chosen arbitrarily, which means the domain of $A\circ A^{-1}$ is the whole of $B$, which is a contradiction because then it has a larger domain than $A^{-1}$!

Comment: If $A$ is an operator on $B$ then how can its domain be a proper subset of $B$?

Comment: You just defined $A$ as an operator on $B$ and seconds later the domain of $A$ is a proper subset of $B$; what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I meant the range of $A$!

Comment: I also meant to say 'domain' rather than 'range' in the last line, fixed now. Sorry about that.

Comment: But the identity on an infinite dimensional Banach soace isn't compact?

Answer (score 1):

If  $C$ is a closed subset of $B $ $ and $ if $C$ is a subset of the image $A(B),$   which is the domain of $A^{-1}$, then we have $(AA^{-1})(C)=C$,which ( of course) is  closed in $B.$

BUT if $C$ is closed in $B$ but $C$ is not a subset of $A(B)$ then $(AA^{-1})(C)=(AA^{-1})(C\cap A(B))=C\cap A(B)$, which may fail to be closed in $B$.

SO  if $f\not \in dom (A^{-1})=A(B)$ then the argument "... by the closedness of $AA^{-1}... $" applied to the closed set $C=\{f\}\cup \{f_n\}_n)$  (...which claims that $(AA^{-1})(C)$ is closed in $B$...) is not valid because $C\not\subset dom (A^{-1}).$

Comment: By 'closed linear operator  $A$' I mean a linear operator with the property that for any sequence $x_n$ in $B$ that converges to some $x\in B$ and so that $A x_n \to y$, then $y$ is in the domain of $A$ and $Ax=y$. This definition is given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator#Closed_linear_operators

Comment: Oh sorry I think I see what you're saying. I guess the problem with the argument in my question is that I incorrectly assume that the composition of two closed linear operators is also closed?